# print json object like {key:value} by jq utiliity

Tags: json, jq

i have json:

```
{
  "ssh_key": 
    {
      "id": 123,
      "public_key": "ssh-rsa 1233123333333333333dafseg345345345",
      "name": "MY.PUB.KEY",
      "fingerprint": "94:45:54:22:3f:55:ff:55"
    }
}
```

i can't print only 1 object **{"id":123}** with jq, i tryed like this:

```
jq '.ssh_key | to_entries[] | {"id": .key, "value": .value.id}'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "id"
```

Comment: `jq '.ssh_key | {id}'`?

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: If you actually want just the id (not an object), `jq -r .ssh_key.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working solution:

```
jq '.ssh_key | {id}'
```

which outputs:

```
{
  "id": 123
}
```